# What happens when I edit my suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Suppose I just proposed an edit (clicked someone else's question's edit button and posted that), and then I remember I forgot to make another edit, after which I press the edit button again and make corrections. But the first edit hasn't taken place yet.

Does my initial suggested edit get edited or is there another suggested edit posted? Do reviewers see the changes live, or are they reviewing the version the site loaded for them, and it doesn't update?

Comment: My understanding is that the initial suggestion is edited, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Depends on whether anyone has reviewed it yet or not, I think.  It would be odd if someone rejected your edit if it looked bad, then the next person flagged the previous person for rejecting a perfectly acceptable edit (because it's changed in the meantime).

Comment: Reviewers flag other reviewers? Is there an FAQ article on that?

Comment: @user1306322: I should have been more clear: some people may flag one of the person's post with a "other" reason, providing that this reviewer is not doing their job properly - this is the currently accepted way of bringing bad reviewers to the attention of moderators.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While your suggested edit is still pending review, you are in your grace period. Any further edits you make will get combined into the pending suggestion.

If your edit has already been approved (or perhaps rejected) and review has completed, further edits will create a new suggestion for review.