# The FAQ is unclear about the grace period for suggested edits

Tags: discussion, edits

The [main FAQ for editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) explains how their grace period works:

> #### Grace period
>
> In order to prevent a series of tiny edits from showing up in the revision history, a single user who edits a post is given a 5-minute [grace period](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info), *except* under one of the following conditions:
>
> - The previous revision was a rollback.
> - The new revision is a rollback.
>
> During this period, any additional edits they make are collapsed into the same edit in the revision history, displaying only the final outcome of all their edits within that 5 minute period. The grace period ends after exactly 5 minutes, or if:
>
> - Another user edits the post, at which time *their* grace period begins.
> - A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor (ignores deleted comments).
> - If the post being edited is a question and an answer has been added since the previous revision (ignores deleted answers).
> - The question has been closed since the previous revision.

However, it doesn't mention that the grace period for **suggested** edits is actually different, as [explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202282/what-happens-when-i-edit-my-suggested-edit/202288#202288):

> **While your suggested edit is still pending review, you are in your grace period**. Any further edits you make will get combined into the pending suggestion.
>
> If your edit has already been approved (or perhaps rejected) and review has completed, further edits will create a new suggestion for review.

In other words, a suggested edits grace period can be much shorter or longer than the normal 5 minutes users might expect. And the actions that end an edits grace period don't appear to affect suggested edits.

The [editing FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) *does* link to [the FAQ entry on suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) but **that makes no mention of a grace period**.

---

#### Suggestion:

- add an entry on the grace period to the Suggested Edits FAQ.
- mention in the grace period section of the Editing FAQ that the grace period for suggested edits is different and link to that FAQ

Comment: It's a CW and you're talking about adding info that's already in "official" verbiage... Seems like you can just add this?

Comment: @Catija I asked if could just change it [on chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6277876#6277876) but didn't get much of a response and there was some confusion on what exactly should be changed. I figured I'd just make a post here so it gets some more visibility in case my interpretation is off.